# Custom HDMI mode Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: hdmi, config.txt

I'm new to the Raspberry community and I'm trying to get the Raspberry to display on my iMac through Target Display Mode (TDM). This works fine, but only up to 720p, since the iMac can only work in TDM if it's 720p or native (`2560*1440`).

Sadly, 1440p is not a standard supported resolution in the list of HDMI modes. That's when I found [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24679) (from 2012!), which explained how to make a custom HDMI mode.

When I added `hdmi_cvt=2560 1440 60 3` (2560 * 1440, 60hz, 16:9) and tried to get the list of available modes (`tvservice -m DMT`), it didn't show up. I suspect that this way of adding custom HDMI-groups is no longer supported.

I put it at the bottom of my `config.txt`, might that be the problem? Does location matter within the config-file?

I would really like to have my Raspberry Pi to display on the native resolution of the iMac, so if anyone can help me out setting up a custom HDMI mode, that would be perfect!

Comment: The thread you reference is from 2012, assuming the details are from the same time frame, this was designed for the model B, not the newer Pi model 2. as a result it may no longer apply. However, you may want to check this config.txt reference https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md especially the HDMI group custom groups and mode settings.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, @SteveRobillard. The weird thing is, that the official (?) Raspberry Pi site still links to this forum (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) and even has the above technique on that site (cmd+f for `CUSTOM MODE`). Is there a new way to add a custom resolution?

Comment: Note, I did not say it definitely won't work, just that it may not! Check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Ah yes, exactly the link I wrote in my comment ;) They mention the same technique. Guess I'll play a bit more with it in the weekend. Does location in the config-file matter? (I have the line at the bottom now, not close to `hdmi_group` etc.)

Comment: The order should not matter, but for organization you should group related things together. Having said that i would duplicate the order they are presented in the reference just to be sure.